# How to iterate over a loop

Tags: r, iteration

I would like to do this automatically instead of typing it out 1500 times.

```
n1 <- spei[sp_latong[[1]]$lon_indx,sp_latong[[1]]$lat_indx,ind_time]
.
.
.
n1500 <- spei[
  sp_latong[[1500]]$lon_indx,
  sp_latong[[1500]]$lat_indx,
  ind_time ]  
         ### create final data
dat1 <- cbind(n1,n2,...,n1500)
```

I tried using a loop and I have the code below:

```
    t <- 0
    for(i in 1: length(sp_latong){
    t[[i]] < - 
    spei[sp_latong[[i]]$lon_indx,sp_latong[[i]]$lat_indx,ind_time]  
    }
```

I got an error message

> Error in spei[sp_latong[[i]]$lon_indx, sp_latong[[i]]$lat_indx] :
>     incorrect number of dimensions.

I had to change t[[i]] to t[i] and also to t and I got the same error message. Any advice will be appreciated.

NB: spei is a large array
    sp_latong is list

Comment: Probably you might do it using `apply` family or `purrr` library. Could you give us an example of your data? Use `dput(data)` or `dput(head(df))` to a small sample.

Comment: @Dave2e I tried it but got the 50 warning messages. Here is one of the messages In t[i] <- spei[sp_latong[[i]]$lon_indx, sp_latong[[i]]$lat_indx,  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Have you in your code `< -` ? you want `<-`

Comment: I use the vector command as advised but got the error message In t[i] <- spei[sp_latong[[i]]$lon_indx, sp_latong[[i]]$lat_indx,  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Your error is mentioned above is referring to this line `spei[sp_latong[[i]]$lon_indx, sp_latong[[i]]$lat_indx, ind_time]`.  By adding "ind_time" you have specified a 3rd dimension for this array.  Without see a sample of your data it is difficult to understand what your intentions are.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the code below based it on Dave2e ideas

```
    t<- list()
    for(i in 1:length(sp_latong)){

    t[[i]] <- spei[sp_latong[[i]]$lon_indx,sp_latong[[i]]$lat_indx,ind_time]

    }
```

@ Dave2e thank you very much.

Comment: or short: `t <- lapply(sp_latong, function(sp) spei[sp$lon_indx, sp$lat_indx, ind_time])`